# select 2 jquery custom attribute country name with capital name

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, html-select

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to select 2 options, Even if I search with "data-name" the option should show up

```
 <select name="countries" class="vat" id="example">
        <option value="USA" data-name="Newyork" selected="selected">United States</option>
        <option value="UK"  data-name="london">Unied Kingdom</option>
        <option value="DE"  data-name="Berlin">Germany</option>
    </select>
```

I'm trying to approach in the search, if I type berlin, Germany should show up on the select list

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#example").select2().find(":selected").data("name");
        });
    </script>
```

Please try to help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matcher method of *select2* plugin . So ,whenever user typed inside input-box you can filter options inside select-box using `..indexOf(input_value)`. If the value is `true` then option will be shown else it will get hidden.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2({
    "width": "150px",
    matcher: function(term, text, option) {
      //get input box value 
      var input_value = $(".select2-input").val().toLowerCase();
      //get the data attribute value..
      var data_name = $(option[0]).data("name").toLowerCase();
      //if match ..show that option
      return data_name.indexOf(input_value) != -1 || option[0].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(input_value) != -1;
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="countries" class="vat" id="example">
  <option value="USA" data-name="Newyork" selected="selected">United States</option>
  <option value="UK" data-name="london">Unied Kingdom</option>
  <option value="DE" data-name="Berlin">Germany</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, Just what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can search the state and country will show

```
<input list="brow">
<datalist id="brow">
        <option value="USA" data-name="Newyork" selected="selected">new york, florida</option>
        <option value="UK"  data-name="london">london</option>
        <option value="DE"  data-name="Berlin">berlin, other states</option>
  
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i was looking into the other way like select 2 options